# Сохранение AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, аудио

Применяю эффекты к файлу использую Node. Пытаюсь все это дело сохранить, однако, не ясно как сохранять файлы... На данный момент пытаюсь делать так:

```
- (IBAction)saveFile:(id)sender{
NSDate *newDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormater setTimeStyle:kCFDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSString *Time;
NSString *strDate = [dateFormater stringFromDate:newDate];
Time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"NewFile%@",strDate];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"_"];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", " withString:@"_"];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@"_"];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"_"];
Time = [Time stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".." withString:@"_"];
Time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Time];

// create the save panel
if(isEmpty){
    NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    [alert setMessageText:@"Oh, i don't see any files"];
    [alert runModal];
}
else{
    NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    //---------------------------------------------------
    // set a new file name
    [panel setNameFieldStringValue:Time];
    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"wav", nil]];
    //---------------------------------------------------
    if( [panel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton ){

        //NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSURL *savePath = panel.URL;

        NSString *save = [savePath path];



        Output = engine.outputNode;

        AudioUnit *Unit;
        Unit = Output.audioUnit;
        // Подготовить формат
        AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
        memset(&asbd, 0, sizeof(asbd));
        asbd.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
        asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked; //kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
        asbd.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
        asbd.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
        asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
        asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        asbd.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
        asbd.mBytesPerPacket = 4;

        // acs.outputFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;



        AudioFileID OutputFile;
        CFStringRef inputFile = (__bridge CFStringRef)(save);
        CFURLRef inputFileURL = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, inputFile, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle,false);
        CheckError (AudioFileCreateWithURL(inputFileURL, kAudioFileWAVEType, &asbd, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile, &OutputFile), "не могу записать пакеты в файл");
        CFRelease(inputFileURL);
        float y = 6871947*16;//audio.length;
        myData1 = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(__bridge void * _Nonnull)(Output) length:y freeWhenDone:NO];
        // UInt16 *data1 = (UInt16*) malloc (&Output);
        //y = 6871947*6;
        //UInt32 length = (UInt32)[myData1 length]-4096; // 4096 - непонятное число
        NSUInteger length1 = [myData1 length]-4096; // 4096 - непонятное число

        UInt32 lgt = (UInt32) length1/4;
        UInt16 *cdata = (UInt16*) malloc (length1);

        [myData1 getBytes:(void*)cdata range:NSMakeRange(0, length1)];

        CheckError (  AudioFileWritePackets(OutputFile, TRUE, lgt, NULL, 0, &lgt, cdata), "не могу записать пакеты в файл");

        AudioFileClose(OutputFile);

    }
}
```

}

Но судя по всему напрямую сохранять OutputNode не стоит. Получаю писки и трески.
Как реализовать сохранение, если я использую AVAudioPlayerNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю поможет или нет, но на всякий случай поделюсь информацией.

- [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/10779)
- [Линк на исходники от Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Линк на SO(все очень подробно)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679061/can-i-use-avaudioengine-to-read-from-a-file-process-with-an-audio-unit-and-writ)

Comment: 3  ссылка очень помогла. Остальные видел